# no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘node’) in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to implement linked list in c. I am passing head struct node to all of the function using double linked list. I am taking the help of
[How do I modify a pointer that has been passed into a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c). I don't know where I am wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void choice(struct node **);
void Insert(struct node **);
void Display(struct node **);
void Search();


struct node 
{
    int value;
    struct node *link;
};



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{


    struct node *head = NULL;

    choice(&head);

    return 0;
}


void choice(struct node **head)
{
    int choice;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter your choice: \n");

        printf(" 1. Insert a list\n 2. Display the list\n 3. Search the list\n : ");

        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: Insert(head);break;
            case 2: Display(head);break;
            case 3: Search();break;
        }
    }

}

void Insert(struct node *head)
{
    int new_value;
    printf("Enter the value to be inserted: \n");
    scanf("%d",&new_value);
    if ( **head == NULL )
    {
        printf("head is NULL\n");
        **head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        (**head) -> value = new_value;
        **head -> link = NULL;

    }

    else
    {
        struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        new_node -> value = new_value;

        new_node -> link = NULL;

        struct node *temp = *head;

        while ( temp -> link != NULL )
        {
            temp = temp -> link;
        }

        temp -> link = new_node;
    }
    Display(head);


}

void Display(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp = *head;

    while ( temp -> link != NULL )
    {
        printf("The value is: %d\n", temp -> value );
    }

}

void Search()
{

}
```

I am getting errors like:

> ```
>   /home/shahjahan/Desktop/interview/datastructure/ll.c: In function ‘void Insert(node*)’:
> /home/shahjahan/Desktop/interview/datastructure/ll.c:56:7: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘node’)
>   if ( **head == NULL )
>        ^
> /home/shahjahan/Desktop/interview/datastructure/ll.c:59:3: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘node’)
>    **head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
>    ^
> /home/shahjahan/Desktop/interview/datastructure/ll.c:60:4: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘node’)
>    (**head) -> value = new_value;
>     ^
> /home/shahjahan/Desktop/interview/datastructure/ll.c:61:3: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘node’)
>    **head -> link = NULL;
>    ^
> /home/shahjahan/Desktop/interview/datastructure/ll.c:73:24: error: cannot convert ‘node’ to ‘node*’ in initialization
>    struct node *temp = *head;
>                         ^
> /home/shahjahan/Desktop/interview/datastructure/ll.c:82:14: error: cannot convert ‘node*’ to ‘node**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void Display(node**)’
>   Display(head);
>               ^
> /home/shahjahan/Desktop/interview/datastructure/ll.c: In function ‘void Display(node*)’:
> /home/shahjahan/Desktop/interview/datastructure/ll.c:89:23: error: cannot convert ‘node’ to ‘node*’ in initialization
>   struct node *temp = *head;
>                        ^
> [Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
> ```

Comment: Compare the function prototypes with the actual function definitions.

Comment: Of course. You're declaring them type **, but defining them type *. The C compiler can't read your mind, you have to tell exactly how much indirection to use when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the second * in the function definition for Insert. You are passing it a double-indirect and using it as a double-indirect but defining it as a single-indirect. I would change the line

```
void Insert(struct node *head)
```

to read

```
void Insert(struct node **head)
```

and then change the Display call at the end to be

```
Display(*head)
```

Also, your loop in Display() is infinite, as it doesn't do any counting and cannot be broken out of.