# Removing characters from original string?

Tags: c

This may be basic, please be patient with me,

```
char data[]="(xxx)";
```

I would like to remove the () and leave **data** only to be `xxx`  ,

```
char *p = strtok(data,"(");
p = strtok(NULL,")");
printf("this data: %s \n",p);
printf("this data: %s \n",data);
```

1. p should be xxx but its NULL , data stay the same (strtok should affect the source?)
2. this will not change data, I would like a way to manipulate data to be `xxx`

Comment: What about `"a(xxx)b"`?

Comment: It is not very clear what you're asking

Comment: @layzak take a any word with () and just remove the () from the original word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *in_parens(char* str) {
   char *end, *start;
   if (!(end = strrchr(str, ')'))) return NULL;
   if (!(start = strchr(str, '('))) return NULL;
   *end = '\0';
   return start + 1;
}

int main(void) {
    char data[] = "a(x(b)x)c";
    printf("%s\n", in_parens(data)); // prints x(b)x
}
```

Returns `NULL` if string doesn't contain a `()` pair. Otherwise, strips outermost pair and returns what's inside.

Comment: great thats what I needed, so just call it and pass data ? how would I change original "Data" array with this ?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that `str` is modified.

Comment: I am not sure how to use that to change data..

Comment: data= in_parens(data) ?

Comment: Added an example usage.

Comment: @a3f thank you very much. I know its basic stuff, but why are you return a value and not just assign str ?

Comment: @Curnelious `str` is local to in_parens. Arguments are passed by value in C. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c

Comment: @a3f your example btw is not removing the first "(" ,  try data="(a+5)";

Comment: @snr People can downvote and do so. Your answer is ok though. @Curnelious `char data[] = "(a+5)";` works for me.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
memmove(data, data + 1, sizeof data - 1);  // Removes the (
data[strlen(data) -1] = '\0';  // Removes the )
```

Note that the above solution only works on the data as initially presented, with a leading and trailing parentheses. It also only works if `data` is actually an array and not a pointer. And the array `data` needs to be in modifiable memory (e.g. RAM).

Also note that is the requirements in the paragraph is met, then the order of the two statements doesn't matter.

Comment: What about `a(xxx)b` ? a3f mentioned not elegant but acceptable

Comment: Thanks I can't use memmove its a micro processor environment, any other option ?

Comment: look at my comment @Curnelious are you kiddy boy oh my gosh

Comment: @snr Not part of the original question. Only added as a comment by the OP. :)

Comment: @Curnelious Using `memmove` will work ousing any standard-compliant C compiler. It won't work if the array is in some kind of read-only memory. You need to be *specific* when writing questions, including environments, *all* requirements, limitations etc.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry, thanks I am checking if this solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a char[], not string. You can try something like this :

```
char new_Data[sizeof(data)/sizeof(char)];
for(i=1 ; i < sizeof(new_Data) ; i++){
        new_Data[i] = data[i];
}
```

This may work only if "(" and ")" are at the end of your char*

Comment: "It's a char*, not a string." 1) OP never mentioned either of those, so what are you talking about? 2) It's not a `char*`, it's a `char[]`. Huge difference.

Comment: Sorry. I just edit my post

Comment: thanks, this is not answering my question , its a new var, and also why strtok not affecting data?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work because `strtok`does not work the way you think it does. When called the first time like this:

```
char *p = strtok(data,"(");
```

It will:

1. skip until the first char that's not a delimiter.
2. then try to find the next delimiter.
3. replace the *last* delimiter with a `\0`.
4. return a pointer to the first char of the token.

Since step two fails (there are no more delimiters) strtok will simply return `NULL` indicating that it didn't find any tokens. Any further calls to `strtok` for the same input will also return `NULL`.

You can change this by adding the ending delimiter in the first call like this:

```
char *p = strtok(data,"()");
```

Now `strtok` will find a token, and return a pointer to the first `x` in your example. Notice though, that since it only replaced the terminating delimiter with a `\0`, the opening parentesis is still present in `data`.

To get rid of that one you could do something like this:

```
char *p = strtok(data,"()");
strcpy(data, p);
```

However I would rather recommend building a new string for the results if you have any other content in the source data as well.

Answer (score -1):

The code takes two strings, which first is the complete one, the other is which characters to being deleted. You can specify like `()qwer`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strip_chars(const char *string, const char *chars)
{
    char * newstr = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    int counter = 0;

    for ( ; *string; string++) {
        if (!strchr(chars, *string)) {
            newstr[ counter ] = *string;
            ++counter;
        }
    }

    newstr[counter] = 0;
    return newstr;
}

int main()
{
    char *new = strip_chars("(xxx)", "()");
    printf("%s\n", new);

    free(new);
    return 0;
}
```