# How can I solve this problem with pointers in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers

In the code below, I'm trying to implement a function that finds the maximun and minimun of a given array. But I was trying to use a different approach. I was trying to change the memory adress of the pointers for the maximum and minimum.

Why this is not working? Should I use pointers to pointers for solving this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 5

void maxMin(int *v, int N, int *max, int *min){
    int i;
    printf("%d\n",*v);
    printf("%d\n",*max);
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++){
        if(*max < *(v+i)){
            max = (v+i);
        }
        if(*min > *(v+i)){
            min = (v+i);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int v[M] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8}, *max=v, *min=v;
    maxMin(v, M, max, min);

    printf("MAX %d\n", *max);
    printf("MIN %d\n", *min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `max` points at the array. When you pass `max` you pass a pointer. The function receives a _copy_ of that pointer. When you modify it inside the function, the caller won't see it. To modify the pointer and let the caller see it, pass a "double pointer", i.e., the _address_ of the pointer.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but there is some confusion between the argument N and the global macro M in your code. It causes no problems in your example, because they are identical, but maxMin should refer to "N" in its body rather than "M".

Comment: Remember that C passes arguments *by value*, which means the argument variables inside a function are ***copies***. And modifying a copy will not modify the original. Please do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c

Answer (score 3):

You should use double pointers because passing it like this will copy the value of the pointers.

```
void maxMin(int *v, int N, int **max, int **min){
    int i;
    int minVal = *v;
    int maxVal = *v;
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++){
        if(maxVal < *(v+i)){
            maxVal = *(v+i);
            *max = (v+i);
        }
        if(minVal > *(v+i)){
            minVal = *(v+i);
            *min = (v+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call the function like this.

```
maxMin(v, M, &max, &min);
```

The rest stays the same.

Comment: I think there's a typo. The parameter is `int N` but the for-loop refers to `M`.

Comment: @AustinMullins Its like this in the question. It is probably a typo but it is not mine :). Look at the macro M in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why you need to use pointers here, is because you wish to return both min and max, but a function only has one return value. Therefore, you have to return them through the parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 5

void maxMin(size_t n, const int v[n], int *max, int *min)
{
  *max = v[0];
  *min = v[0];

  for(size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    if(*max < v[i])
    {
      *max = v[i];
    }
    if(*min > v[i]){
      *min = v[i];
    }
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  int v[M] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8};
  int max;
  int min;

  maxMin(M, v, &max, &min);

  printf("MAX %d\n", max);
  printf("MIN %d\n", min);
  return 0;
}
```

(Returning two pointers that point at the max and min elements would be a weird interface - in that case you would rather return the indices where max and min could be found.)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value(that is the starting address of array) stored in pointers `max` and `min` to the function `maxMin()` with `maxMin(v, M, max, min)` . What this means is that the pointer variables `min` and `max` in `main()` are related to `min` and `max` pointer variables in `maxMin()` argument list. So any change done to these variables in `maxMin()` will not be reflected in `main()`.

What you need to do is pass the address of `min` and `max` variables and update the values of the `*min` and `*max` in the function `maxMin`(See Petar Velev answer).