# Why use double pointer when inserting node to the head (linkedlist)?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
int list_insert_head(node **phead, int data){
  node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
  if(newnode == 0)
    return 0; /*memory allocation failed*/
  newnode -> data = data;
  newnode -> next = *phead;
  *phead = newnode; /* what is this?*/
  return 1;

}
```

So I'm not quite sure why you have to pass in double pointer **phead,
and only use a single pointer *phead inside the function. 
I assume you use double pointer b/c you're manipulating actual head, which itself is a single pointer. 
Inside the function by the way, if you were going to do this,

```
*phead = newnode;
```

why don't you just pass in *phead in the function parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't use a double pointer you'll be asking *this* question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c

Comment: The question is not a duplicate *per se*, but the answer would be. ;-) So I closed the question as such.

Comment: @DevSolar - I edited another posts into the dupe list. All bases should be covered now.

Comment: If you haven't already, please see what happens when a double pointer is not used. That should give some idea.