# Access violation in malloc

Tags: c

while running the code below in C (visual studio 2019), I get Access violation error in the "SetArr" function

the program stops and exits with this message.

any help will be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void SetArr(int** arr, int rowNum, int colNum);
void zeros(int** arr, int rowNum, int colNum);

int **arr1, **arr2;

int i, j, input,output;

int main() {
    zeros(arr1, 2, 3);
    SetArr(arr1, 2, 3);

}

void zeros(int** arr, int rowNum, int colNum) {
    arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * rowNum);
    for (i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * colNum);
    }
}

void SetArr(int **arr, int rowNum, int colNum) {
    for (i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
            scanf_s("%d", &input);
            arr1[i][j] = input;
        }
    }`
}
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c

Answer (score 3):

C uses pass-by-value for all function argument passing.

Just like if you want to modify a variable passed as an argument in the called function and have that change reflect in the caller, you pass address of that variable, same way, if you want to modify a pointer, you need to pass the address of that pointer.

Call you function like

```
 zeros(&arr1, 2, 3);
```

and in the function, use it like

```
void zeros(int*** arr, int rowNum, int colNum) {
    *arr = malloc(sizeof(int*) * rowNum);
    for (i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
        (*arr)[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * colNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, If I have `int a[1]` and call `foo(a)`, and not "pass address of that variable," `&a` as suggested, The value of `a` (the array's contents) can certainly change.  From the caller's point-of-view, acts like pass by reference.  IOWs, C does not have so much "pass-by-value" restriction always as much as "received by value" given the hidden array to address of the first element conversion.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Does it not like in most cases, including when passing as function argument, a type with array gets converted to pointer to the first element of the array? Also, as array is a collection of a particular member object type, the address of the first element is the address of the array variable itself. So, without the explicit use of unary `&` operator, are we not still passing the address of the variable?

Comment: The point is that `foo(a)` with `int a[1]`, from the caller's point of view, is a pass by reference.  The underlying mechanics do convert the `a` to `&a[0]`, yet that is an implementation detail.  In any case, minor point and good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `arr1` to the `zeros` function by value.  So when you modify it in the function, the change isn't reflected in the calling function.  This means that when you call `SetArr` you're reading an uninitialized pointer.

Change `zeros` to return the pointer that it allocates:

```
int **zeros(int rowNum, int colNum) {
    int arr = malloc(sizeof(int*) * rowNum);
    for (i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * colNum);
    }
}
```

And assign the return value to `arr1`:

```
arr1 = zeros(2, 3);
```