# Trying to remove last element from linked list and save it into a variable passed as parameter giving segfault

Tags: c, linked-list, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have a linked list in which I am trying to remove the last element that is a `char*` and set the parameter I pass into that function to the `char*`. However, this either gives a segfault or prints out gibberish. Why is this happening?

Here is the linked list:

```
  struct list_node {
          char* name;
          struct list_node* next;
  };
  typedef struct list_node node;
```

And here are its functions (I'm pretty sure the other functions work but not the remove_last):

```
  int remove_last(node* head, char* ret) {
          while(head) {
                  if (head->next->next == NULL) {
                          printf("here\n");
                          ret = strdup(head->next->name);
                          printf("%s\n", ret);
                          printf("there\n");
                          //free(head->next);
                          //head->next = NULL;
                          return 0;
                  }
                  head = head->next;
          }
          return -1;
  }

  void add_last(char* name, node* current) {
          node* new_node;
          new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
          while(current) {
                  if (current->next == NULL) {
                          current->next = new_node;
                          new_node->name = name;
                          return;
                  }
                  current = current->next;
          }
  }

  node* add_first(char* name,  node* head) {
          node* new_node;
          new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
          new_node->name = name;
          new_node->next = head;
          head = new_node;
          return head;
  }
```

Inside the function, when I printf `ret`, I get what I am supposed to get, but in my main when I try to print out the `ret` variable I pass into parameters:

```
char *temp = NULL;
remove_last(head, temp);
printf("%s\n", temp);
```

I get a segfault. I originally thought maybe it was because I was setting the nodes and freeing them, but I also used strdup (which I think copies it to a new location or smth like that?). I think it might also have something to do with how I am setting `temp` to null and then I am not setting assigning `ret = name` correctly in the function? Any advice?

Comment: You pass `ret` by value, so `ret = strdup(head->next->name);` will not affect the pointer in the calling function. You can change it to be a `char **`. [How do I modify a pointer that has been passed into a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766905)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function `add_last` is incorrect and can invoke undefined behavior.

Firstly it does not check whether the pointer `current` (I suppose it can be a pointer to the head node) is equal to `NULL`. In this case there is a memory leak because the newly created node is not appended to the list.

Secondly the function does not set the data member `next` of the newly created node to `NULL`

At least the function can be declared and defined the following way if to use your approach to implementing the function `add_first`

```
node * add_last(char* name, node *head ) {
    node* new_node; 
    new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->name = name;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {  
        current = head;

        while ( current->next ) current = current->next;

        current->next = new_node;
    }

    return head;
}
```

As for the function `remove_last` then the function parameter `ret` is a local variable of the function that will not be alive after exiting the function. The function parameter must have the type char **. That is the corresponding argument must be passed by reference to the function.

And in any case the function is incorrect because it ignores a case when the list contains only one node. You need to pass the pointer to the head node also by reference.

The function can look the following way.

```
int remove_last( node **head, char **ret )
{
    int result = *head == NULL ? -1 : 0;

    if ( result == 0 )
    {
        while( ( *head )->next != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *ret = strdup( ( *head )->name );
        free( *head );
        *head = NULL;
    } 

    return result;
}
```