# How to delete the first node of a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I want to delete the first Node of a list (I call it "head") but output give me an error "pointer being freed was not allocated". Do you know where is the issue? Sorry for Italian words if you didn't understand something I can edit my question. I think that the issue is in `void cancellaTriangolo`. Maybe I saved wrong nodes and they don't save themselves.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* STRUTTURE */
typedef struct punto {
    int x;
    int y;
} PUNTO;

typedef struct triangolo {
    PUNTO v;
    int lato;
} TRIANGOLO;

typedef struct nodo {
    TRIANGOLO t;
    struct nodo *next;
} NODO;

/* STAMPA LISTA */
int perimetro(TRIANGOLO t) {
    return t.lato * 3;
}

void stampaTriangolo(TRIANGOLO t) {
    printf("Il triangolo ha il lato uguale a: %d con un perimetro pari a %d, il vertice in alto ha coordinate (%d,%d)\n",
           t.lato, perimetro(t), t.v.x, t.v.y);
}

void stampaLista(NODO *head) {
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        printf("Lista vuota!\n");
    } else {
        while (head->next != NULL) {
            head = head->next;
            stampaTriangolo(head->t);
        }
    }
}

/* INSERIMENTO */
TRIANGOLO creaTriangolo() {
    TRIANGOLO nuovo;
    printf("Inserisci il lato del nuovo triangolo: ");
    scanf("%d", &nuovo.lato);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Inserisci le coordinate del vertice con y maggiore:\n");
    printf("x: ");
    scanf("%d", &nuovo.v.x);
    printf("\n");
    printf("y: ");
    scanf("%d", &nuovo.v.y);
    printf("\n");
    
    return nuovo;
}

void inserisciPerPerimetro(NODO *head) {

    NODO *nuovo = malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    nuovo->t = creaTriangolo();
    nuovo->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = nuovo;
    } else {
        if (perimetro(nuovo->t) < perimetro(head->t)) {
            nuovo->next = head;
            head = nuovo;
        } else {
            while (head->next != NULL && perimetro(head->next->t) < perimetro(nuovo->t)) {
                head = head->next;
            }
            nuovo->next = head -> next;
            head->next = nuovo;
        }
    }
    printf("Inserimento effettuato!\n\n");
}

/* CANCELLAZIONE IN TESTA */
void cancellaTriangolo(NODO *head) {
    NODO *primoNodo = NULL;

    /* lista vuota? */
    if (head == NULL) {
        primoNodo = NULL;
        printf("Lista vuota!\n\n");
    } else {
        primoNodo = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(primoNodo);
        printf("Cancellazione effettuata!\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    /* inizializza la lista */
    NODO *head = malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    head->next = NULL;
    
    int risposta = -1;          // per interazione con utente

    while (risposta != 0) {
        /* richiedi un'operazione all'utente */
        printf("Che operazione vuoi svolgere?\n");
        printf("1 -> Inserisci un triangolo nella lista ordinata secondo il perimetro crescente\n");
        printf("2 -> Cancella il triangolo in testa alla lista\n");
        printf("3 -> Visualizza la lista di triangoli\n");
        printf("0 -> Termina il programma\n");
        scanf("%d", &risposta);

        /* gestisci le operazioni dell'utente */
        if (risposta == 1) {
            inserisciPerPerimetro(head);
        } else
        if (risposta == 2) {
            cancellaTriangolo(head);
        } else
        if (risposta == 3) {
            stampaLista(head);
        } else
        if (risposta == 0) {
            printf("Finito!\n\n");
        } else {
            printf("Selezione non valida!\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do `head = nuovo;` in `inserisciPerPerimetro()` be aware that you are only modifying the variable `head` that is _local to inserisciPerPerimetro()_, not the `head` that is local to `main`.

Comment: Before worrying about _deleting_ you should worry about _creating_ the list in the first place. `inserisciPerPerimetro(head);` does not modify `head`. Parameters are passed by value.

Comment: There are many issues I this code.

Comment: @mmixLinus ok so what have I to write in inserisciPerPerimetro() to save it?However in real if I try to create and save a new node it works!

Comment: @Jabberwocky so what have I to do?lol

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for not getting the question right)

Edit:
The change of paramater `head` in `cancellaTriangolo` won't apply to the `head` in `main` by simply doing `head = head->next` inside that function.
To solve this issue, code below might help:

```
void cancellaTriangolo(NODO** head) {
    if (*head) {
        NODO* p = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(p);
    }
}
```

Call it with `cancellaTriangolo(&head)`.

For other issues like when inserting new node... If you found that new nodes are not being inserted, it might be the same reason. Use `NODO** head` to send the pointer to `head` in order to access and change `head` in functions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your approach of having a head that actually contains no data is wrong and makes your code overly complicated. The first node of a list is by definition the head of the list. If the head is NULL, the list is empty.
2. In C parameters are passed by value, so if you want to modify a pointer that has been passed into a function, you need pointers to pointers. The details are explained in this SO question: [How do I modify a pointer that has been passed into a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c).

You basically want this:

It's not the whole code but only the function that were wrong.

---

```
void stampaLista(NODO* head) {
  NODO* current = head;

  if (current == NULL) {
    printf("Lista vuota!\n");
  }
  else {
    while (current != NULL) {
      stampaTriangolo(current->t);
      current = current->next;
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
}

void inserisciPerPerimetro(NODO** head) {

  NODO* nuovo = malloc(sizeof(NODO));
  nuovo->t = creaTriangolo();
  nuovo->next = NULL;

  if (*head == NULL) {
    *head = nuovo;
  }
  else {
    if (perimetro(nuovo->t) < perimetro((*head)->t)) {
      nuovo->next = *head;
      *head = nuovo;
    }
    else {
      while ((*head)->next != NULL && perimetro((*head)->next->t) < perimetro(nuovo->t)) {
        *head = (*head)->next;
      }
      nuovo->next = (*head)->next;
      *head->next = nuovo;    
    }
  }

  printf("Inserimento effettuato!\n\n");
}

void cancellaTriangolo(NODO** head) {
  NODO* primoNodo = NULL;

  /* lista vuota? */
  if (*head == NULL) {
    primoNodo = NULL;
    printf("Lista vuota!\n\n");
  }
  else {
    primoNodo = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;
    free(primoNodo);
    printf("Cancellazione effettuata!\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  /* inizializza la lista */
  NODO* head = NULL;
  ...
    
    if (risposta == 1) {
      inserisciPerPerimetro(&head);  // use &head
    }
    else if (risposta == 2) {
      cancellaTriangolo(&head);      // use &head
    }
    ...
```

Comment: thank you very very much!Only one thing: for "inserisciPerPerimetro" and "cancellaTriangolo" are another way using only a *? Because I'm not sure if I can use it at school

Comment: Why should you not be able to use it at school? It's perfectly legal and clean. But anyway, you could drop the `*` I added at various places and return the new head via `return head`; And call it like this: `head = cancellaTriangolo(head);`. Same for `inserisciPerPerimetro`.

Comment: yeah I know but we have to use only a *(don't ask me why lol).However I have to remove all * or only where there are two?and the func will became NODO* in this case?

Comment: @DanieleSadun, no only remove the `*` where I added one. Basically your functions will be identical to your original functions (except the first node mess I removed), but at the end you just add `return head;`

Comment: @DanieleSadun the function will become `NODO *cancellaTriangolo(...`

Comment: I tried but I have to change void func with "NODO* cancellaTriangolo(NODO *head)" and NODO* primoNodo = NULL.(also for inserisciPerPerimetro).and for both return head.I tried to execute and work all perfectly! Is it ok in this way?

Comment: @DanieleSadun if it works as expected, it's probably OK.