# Value of pointer not updating in function C

Tags: c

I am trying to change a character of a char* passed into a function, but am either getting seg faults or the value of t in main is not updating. How can I update the value in main function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int func (char r, char* i){
    i = "hello";
    char strclone[5];
    strcpy(strclone, i);
    strclone[0] = 'j';
    i = &strclone;
}
int main() {
    char* t;
    func('0', t);
    printf(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One part of the problem is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c

Comment: `char* t;` in `main` has no value: neither a pointer value, or any data content pointed  to.

Comment: What output do you expect? `jello`? What is the use of the `r` parameter in `func`? Did you mean `strclone[0] = r;`? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: You're just reassigning `char* t` in `int func` which doesn't change the content of the pointer but also doesn't change the value of the pointer in main either.

Comment: `strcpy(strclone, i);` causes *buffer overflow*. Change `char strclone[5];` to `char strclone[6];` better yet to `char strclone[100];` Never work with a "I am short of memory but I think this should be big enough" buffer unless you really are.

Comment: Compiler not issuing any warnings?

Comment: I am trying to make t='jello' after the function call, in any way. (basically change the furst character given a string). there are no compiler warnings, and I changed to strclone[100] and same problem. the r parameter is not used in this example.