# Resizing dynamic arrays in c

Tags: c, realloc

How do you properly resize an array using `realloc` so that the newly allocated array can have the data from the previous array plus the newly received data

```
int receiver (int soc_desc, char * buffer)
{
    char *arr; 
    size_t received =0 , total_received=0;
    char buff[MAX+1];
    memset(buff , 0 , MAX+1);
    while (1)
    {
        received = recv(soc_desc, buff , MAX , 0 );
        if (received <= 0 )
            break;
        else
        {
            total_received = total_received + strlen(buff);
            buffer = realloc(buffer, total_received);
            printf("Total: %ld received: %ld \n",total_received , received);
            strcat(buffer, buff);
        }
        printf("%s\n",buff);
    } 
    printf("Final result: %s \n", buffer);
```

in this function, we pass a socket descriptor and a `char *buffer = malloc(MAX)` we receive data and add it to the allocated buffer and then try to reallocate the buffer for the next chunk of data, is there a way to resize the original `malloc`d  `buffer` so that I can fit more characters in it without creating a new pointer for `realloc` each time it is called

when I compile and run this code with valgrind I get

```
==13850==  Address 0x4a5c0e3 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==13850==    at 0x483DFAF: realloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13850==    by 0x109884: ??? (in /home/User/Desktop/test)
==13850==    by 0x109476: ??? (in /home/User/Desktop/test)
==13850==    by 0x48870B2: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)

.
.
.
.

==13850== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13850==     in use at exit: 27 bytes in 1 blocks
==13850==   total heap usage: 22 allocs, 22 frees, 15,807 bytes allocated
```

since `buffer` is a function parameter I used `free(buffer)` outside the function

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to pointer in order to modify it inside the function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I modify a pointer that has been passed into a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c)

Comment: The `realloc` function might have increased the size of the buffer at the same address or it might have allocated a new buffer at a different address and have copied the data. So there is no way around allowing the pointer to change. Note that `buffer = realloc(buffer, total_received);` is wrong because `realloc`  might return `NULL` on errors. The correct way would be something like `tmpbuf = realloc(buffer, total_received); if(tmpbuf != NULL) { buffer = tmpbuf; } else { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: @UnholySheep can you explain in an answer how to do this

Comment: @Bodo I used your method and it seems to work but when i try to check with valgrind it throws a seg fault but works fine without it

Comment: @epic_rain A segmentation fault is often related to errors in other parts of the code.

Comment: `strlen(buff)` is not a good idea, and will give you a wrong result. You have received exactly `received` characters. Use that number. `strcat` is no good here either, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Compile using `-g3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra` flags to get line number of error in `valgrind` and other sort of warnings.

Also, `realloc()` copies previous data to new one.

##### Some Points:

- `total_received = total_received + strlen(buff);` can be written as `total_received += strlen(buff);`
- You need to take `buffer` as `char **buffer` and then de-reference it like `(*buffer)`, so that modification of `buffer` can be done permanently in another function's scope
- `"%zu"` is valid format specifier for `size_t`
- Make sure that `buffer` is heap-allocated in its definition scope
- `memset(buff , 0 , MAX+1);` can be written as `char buff[MAX+1] = {};`
- I don't see any use of `arr` variable in `receiver()` function
- *NOTE: Make sure that new size for `buffer` is larger than the previous size*
- Always check whether heap allocation was successful or not, by checking the pointer against `NULL`, eg., `if(!buffer) { /* error */ }`
- Pass `buffer` like `&buffer` [give address of `buffer` to `receiver()` function]
- `received` is `unsigned long int` AKA `size_t` which means it starts from 0, hence checking for less than 0 is not required, instead check for `(received == 0)`
- Use `memcpy()` to append `buff` to `*buffer` by limiting the length of `buff`
- Append null terminating character at the very end of `*buffer`

##### Final Code:

```
int receiver(int soc_desc, char **buffer)
{
    char *arr; // idk
    size_t received = 0, total_received = 0;
    char buff[MAX + 1] = {}; // every element is now 0
    while (1)
    {
        received = recv(soc_desc, buff, MAX, 0);
        if (received == 0)
            break;
        else
        {
            total_received += received;
            (*buffer) = realloc(*buffer, total_received + 1);
            if (*buffer == NULL) // error occurred
            {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Total: %zu received: %zu\n", total_received, received);
            memcpy(*buffer, buff, received);
            (*buffer)[total_received + 1] = 0; // nul terminating character
        }
        printf("%s\n", buff);
    }
    printf("Final result: %s \n", *buffer);

    /*your rest of the code */
```

Comment: This is very useful but as far as i understood this only makes code more readable and does not solve my issue (correct me on that if i am wrong )

Comment: @epic_rain There shall be other issue in rest of your code

Comment: @epic_rain Are you calling `realloc()` in other part of your code?

Comment: no this is the only function where i use `realloc`

Comment: @epic_rain "this only makes code more readable"  no, it solves a very real problem with your code. Namely, that your assignment to `buffer` is invisible outside of `receiver`. There are several other unsolved problems still.

Comment: You can't use `strlen` and `strcat` because `buff` isn't NUL-terminated. `strlen(buff)` should be replaced with `received`, and `strcat(*buffer, buff)` needs to be replaced with a `memcpy`. Also, you need to return the amount read (or add a NUL).

Comment: `memcpy(*buffer, buff, received);` is wrong. You are just throwing away everything received in the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc):

> Reallocates the given area of memory. It must be previously allocated by `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` and not yet freed with a call to free or realloc. Otherwise, the results are undefined.
>
> The reallocation is done by either:
>
> a) expanding or contracting the existing area pointed to by `ptr`, if possible. The contents of the area remain unchanged up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. **If the area is expanded, the contents of the new part of the array are undefined. (*)**
>
> b) allocating a new memory block of size `new_size` bytes, copying memory area with size equal the lesser of the new and the old sizes, and freeing the old block.
>
> **If there is not enough memory, the old memory block is not freed and null pointer is returned. (#)**

The formatting (bold text) and **(*)** and **(#)** have been added, and were not in the quoted text.

Solving **(#)**:

```c
bool realloc_buffer(void **buffer, size_t new_size)
{
    void *tmp = *buffer;
    *buffer = realloc(*buffer, new_size);
    
    if (!*buffer) { // Realloc failed: restore the old pointer.
        *buffer = tmp;
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Then in your code:

```c
int receiver (int soc_desc, char **buffer)
{
    // ...
    
    if (!realloc_buffer(buffer, old_size + total_received + 1)) { // You should know the old size
        // Handle failure
    }
}
```

You said:

> ... so that the newly allocated array can **have the data from the previous array plus the newly received data**

According to **(*)**, you have to manually append the new data.

```c
int receiver (int soc_desc, char **buffer)
{
    // ...
    
    char *copy = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (old_size+1));
    // Make a copy of the old buffer
    memcpy(copy, buffer, old_size+1);
    
    if (!realloc_buffer(buffer, old_size + total_received + 1)) { // You should know the old size
        // Handle failure
    } else {
        memcpy(buffer + old_size * sizeof(char*), copy, total_received+1);
    }
    
    free(copy);
    // ...
}
```