# C function return address of memory accessed in a function

Tags: c

We have below code in production system written in C and I feel that after below function call the `getptr` variable and the value it refers to will be lost.

- Is the below implementation correct?
- Can we return address from a function like below?
- Should we change option code given after example?

  ```
   U8* MGet(int queueHandle)
   {
        U8* getptr;
        getptr = (U8*)mbox_tryget(queueHandle);
        if(getptr != NULL)
            return getptr  + 4;
        return NULL
    }
  ```

Is the below code correct and resolves the issue:

```
   void MGet(int queueHandle, U8* getptr)
   {
       getptr = (U8*)mbox_tryget(queueHandle);
   }
```

The caller function can now check and validate the value `getptr` is refereeing to.

Comment: The question is pretty unclear. It depends on the general context and on what `mbox_tryget` does. But the second code is obviously wrong.

Comment: Being local `getptr` will be out of scope and therefore lost once the `MGet` function closes, but why do you think that the value returned by the `MGet` function is lost? Is it not handled by the calling code?

Comment: Number 2 is wrong. Show us `mbox_tryget` then we can tell about number 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ....  I feel that after below function call the getptr variable .... to will be lost.

Well, yes... `getptr` inside function is `MGet` is lost. However, that's not an issue because the function returns the value (+4) so as long as the caller saves the returned value all is good. The caller should do like:

```
U8* getptr = MGet(someQueueHandle);
```

> ....  I feel that after below function call ... the value it refers to will be lost.

No, not if `mbox_tryget` is implemented correctly, i.e. if `mbox_tryget` returns NULL or a pointer to a valid object with size at least `4 * sizeof(U8)` then all is good.

> Should we change option code given after example?

No, the second code example is all wrong. Here the value assigned to `getptr` is lost once the function returns so the caller will not get the expected value.

Conclusion:

Stay with the first code example. If something doesn't work then `MGet` is probably wrong but the posted first example code is fine.

End note: This answer assumes that `U8` means something like an 8 bit unsigned char.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want this:

```
void MGet(int queueHandle, U8** getptr)
{
  *getptr = (U8*)mbox_tryget(queueHandle);
}
...
U8 *foo;
MGet(bar, &foo);
```

In your original `MGet`, `getptr = (U8*)mbox_tryget(queueHandle)` has no effect. It just modifies the local variable `getptr`. Function parameters are basically local variables, as in C parameters are passed by value.

But anyway it's still unclear what this +4 in `getptr +4` is for and why there is no +4 in your `MGet` function.

Comment: In my own MGet function (2nd one) the caller will do the arithmetic i.e after the call of MGet function the caller will do the getptr + 4 arithmetic and validate the value.

But what wrong would be in the code is function is called like below for the function of my 2nd version:

U8 *foo;
MGet(bar, foo);

Comment: @Programmer In C parameters are passed by **value**.  This is basic C knowledge and it is documented in the first chapters dealing with function calls in any C text book. [This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c) explains it.

Comment: Quote: "In your original MGet, getptr = (U8*)mbox_tryget(queueHandle) has no effect. It just modifies the local variable getptr". hmm - It saves the value returned and later uses that saved value for generating a return value. That is fine and makes sense.

Comment: @SupportUkraine _"It saves the value returned and later uses that saved value for generating a return value"_ : but it doesn't...

Comment: `return getptr  + 4;`