# Why doesnt the pointer head point to the new node after calling the function?

Tags: c, list, pointers

After calling the function insert start pointer head should point to the newnode where value of variable age is 13 .Instead it returns the same as before like the function doesnt exist.So obviously there is a logical bug and i cant i figure it out

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

   typedef struct person{

         int age;
         struct person* nextnode;

   }person;

   //void insert_end(person*p,int x);

   void insert_start(person*point,int x);

   int main(){

   person*head=NULL;

   person p1={2,NULL};
   person p2={5,NULL};
   head=&p1;
   p1.nextnode=&p2;

   insert_start(head,14);

   printf("%d\n",head->age);

   return 0;
  }


  void insert_start(person*point,int x){

     person*newnode=malloc(sizeof(person));
     newnode->age=x;
     newnode->nextnode=p;


     point=newnode;

  }
```

Comment: Remember that function arguments are passed *by value*. Which means the value used in the call is *copied* into the local argument variable. And as any other local variable, the changes you make to the argument variables will be lost when the function returns. You have two solutions to your problem: 1) Return the new pointer; Or 2) Emulate pass by reference by using a pointer to the variable and pass it using the pointer-to operator `&`.

Comment: The original version of your question has been closed because it is a duplicate. If you didn't understand why, you should post a comment to your original question instead of asking the exact same question again.

Comment: it was mentioned as duplicate but it actually wasnt because i didnt find a question-answer  that face my problem

Comment: @JOHNBOURAS This [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c) is **exactly** about your problem.

Comment: ... `point=newnode;` assigns the **local** variable `point`. It won't modify `head` when you call `insert_start(head,14)`

Comment: @JOHNBOURAS you want `insert_start(&head,14);`. `void insert_start(person **point, int x)` and `*point=newnode;`

Comment: @JOHNBOURAS BTW: your code does not compile, what is `p` in `newnode->nextnode = p;` ?

Comment: @JOHNBOURAS OT: the overall design is wrong, you're mixing dynamically allocated memory with statically allocated memory inside the same list. This is a very bad idea, and it will bite you at latest when you will free the nodes of your list with `free`.