# Swapping array pointers in 3d-stencil not working

Tags: c, pointers, optimization, memory, hpc

I have a 7-point 3d-stencil operation that runs on a 32x32x32 float32 matrix. The matrix is initialized with some values that are **the same** between runs, so there is no random component.

The original implementation below uses a deepcopy approach that copies the values from the B matrix to the A matrix each timestep iteration, so that we end up with 2 identical matrices between each iteration. Note: `arr_t` is just a typedef to `***float`.

```
void stencil_3d_7point(arr_t A, arr_t B, const int nx, const int ny, const int nz)
{
    int i, j, k;
    
    for (int timestep = 0; timestep < MAX_TIME; ++timestep)
    {
        for (i = 1; i < nx - 1; i++)
            for (j = 1; j < ny - 1; j++)
                for (k = 1; k < nz - 1; k++)
                    B[i][j][k] = (A[i - 1][j][k] +
                                  A[i][j - 1][k] +
                                  A[i][j][k - 1] +
                                  A[i][j][k] +
                                  A[i][j][k + 1] +
                                  A[i][j + 1][k] +
                                  A[i + 1][j][k]) /
                                 7.0;

        for (i = 1; i < nx - 1; i++)
            for (j = 1; j < ny - 1; j++)
                for (k = 1; k < nz - 1; k++)
                    A[i][j][k] = B[i][j][k]; // Why not just swap the pointers?


    }
```

My idea is to swap the pointers A and B between iterations, so that we overwrite the old values in A that we are no longer interested in, while reading and operating on the new values from B. See below for that implementation.

```
    for (int timestep = 0; timestep < MAX_TIME; ++timestep)
    {
        for (i = 1; i < nx - 1; i++)
            for (j = 1; j < ny - 1; j++)
                for (k = 1; k < nz - 1; k++)
                    B[i][j][k] = (A[i - 1][j][k] +
                                  A[i][j - 1][k] +
                                  A[i][j][k - 1] +
                                  A[i][j][k] +
                                  A[i][j][k + 1] +
                                  A[i][j + 1][k] +
                                  A[i + 1][j][k]) /
                                 7.0;

        // Swap A and B
        float ***temp = A;
        A = B;
        B = temp;
    }
```

However, these two approaches yield different results. I check this by printing out 10 values from the middle of the 3d matrix.

This is part of the main fuction where I initialize and call the stencil function:

```
    int sz = 32;
    int sx = 32;
    int sy = 32;
    float ***A = (float ***)malloc(sx * sizeof(float **));
    for (i = 0; i < sy; i++)
    {
        A[i] = (float **)malloc(sy * sizeof(float *));
        for (j = 0; j < sz; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = (float *)malloc(sz * sizeof(float));
        }
    }
    float ***B = (float ***)malloc(sx * sizeof(float **));
    for (i = 0; i < sy; i++)
    {
        B[i] = (float **)malloc(sy * sizeof(float *));
        for (j = 0; j < sz; j++)
        {
            B[i][j] = (float *)malloc(sz * sizeof(float));
        }
    }
    // initialize the A matrix

    initValues(A, sx, sy, sz, INNER, OUTER);

    stencil_3d_7point(A, B, sz, sy, sz);
```

The `initValues` function fills the matrices with -1 and 1 values which is the same between execution. Again, no random component to the initial values.

The deepcopy version prints this every execution:
1.000000 0.126466 -0.502245 -0.830534 -0.956082 -0.991445 -0.998770 -0.999873 -0.999991 -0.999999

The pointer swap version prints this every execution:
1.000000 -0.192474 -0.617592 -0.869564 -0.965497 -0.993137 -0.998986 -0.999892 -0.999991 -0.999999

As you can see these are not the same.

The whole purpose of this is to avoid the costly deepcopy operation to save execution cycles.

The compiler and flags used are below:

```
CC = aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
CFLAGS = -O2 -static -march=armv8-a+sve
```

I compile to armv8 to run it in the gem5 simulator.

I've tried printing the same place in both A and B to check if the actual result lies in the other matrix, but that too differs from the deepcopy result.

I've also tried printing the lines at the end of the stencil function instead of after the call in the main function, but that prints the same data. I just tried it to see if the scope has some effect.

This is how the matrices are initialized:

```
void setElement(float ***array, float value, int x, int y, int z)
{
    array[x][y][z] = value;
}

void initValues(float ***array, int sx, int sy, int sz, float inner_temp, float outer_temp)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < (sx - 1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < (sy - 1); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < (sz - 1); k++)
            {
                setElement(array, inner_temp, i, j, k);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < sy; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < sz; k++)
        {
            setElement(array, outer_temp, 0, j, k);
            setElement(array, outer_temp, sx - 1, j, k);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sx; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < sz; k++)
        {
            setElement(array, outer_temp, i, 0, k);
            setElement(array, outer_temp, i, sy - 1, k);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sx; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sy; j++)
        {
            setElement(array, outer_temp, i, j, 0);
            setElement(array, outer_temp, i, j, sz - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

`outer_temp` and `inner_temp` are -1 and 1 respectively.

Below is how I print the values:

```
    // Print 10 first elements of the result
    for (i = 9; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 9; j < 10; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            {
                printf("%f ", A[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                printf("%f ", B[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Update:
I've tried the suggestion of passing pointers pA and pB to the function instead and swapping them like below, but it still doesn't work.

```
void stencil_3d_7point(arr_t *pA, arr_t *pB, const int nx, const int ny, const int nz)
{
    arr_t A = *pA;
    arr_t B = *pB;
    int i, j, k;

    for (int timestep = 0; timestep < MAX_TIME; ++timestep)
    {
        for (i = 1; i < nx - 1; i++)
            for (j = 1; j < ny - 1; j++)
                for (k = 1; k < nz - 1; k++)
                    B[i * ny * nz + j * nz + k] = (A[(i - 1) * ny * nz + j * nz + k] +
                                    A[i * ny * nz + (j - 1) * nz + k] +
                                    A[i * ny * nz + j * nz + (k - 1)] +
                                    A[i * ny * nz + j * nz + k] +
                                    A[i * ny * nz + j * nz + (k + 1)] +
                                    A[i * ny * nz + (j + 1) * nz + k] +
                                    A[(i + 1) * ny * nz + j * nz + k]) /
                                    7.0;
        
    float*** tmp = A;
    A = B;
    B = temp;

    }

    *pA = B;
    *pB = A;
}
```

I call it using the following call:
`stencil_3d_7point(&A, &B, sz, sy, sz);`

Comment: show how are you calling it

Comment: @NickGris I'm a bit unsure about what the normal array declaration is. Ill edit the question with the call and how they are initialized.

Comment: @gulpr I've edited the question with the call to the stencil function and showing how the arrays are initialized.

Comment: You are swapping the local copy of `A` and `B`. That swap is not visible outside of that function as `A` and `B` are passed by value. To change `A` inside that function you need to pass `&A` which has type `arr_t*`

Comment: @SimonEngström add init and pront function too

Comment: @SimonEngström: Apologies, I misunderstood what you were trying to swap - I thought you meant individual entries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I modify a pointer that has been passed into a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Please consider using flatten arrays. jagged array (e.g. `float***`) are pretty inefficient (they tend to increase heap fragmentation and make the indexing significantly more complex, not to mention they can even prevent SIMD optimizations).

Comment: @JérômeRichard The code is vectorizing just fine, both with auto-vectorization and ARM-SVE intrinsics.

Comment: If you don't want to change the signature of the function you could just keep track of how many swaps you did. If you did an even number of swaps, the result is OK. If it was an odd number, you need to do a copy of entries as you did in your first version but this time it is only once at the end of the function.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested and it is not the case with GCC 13.2 on x86-64 at least, though it is not due to jagged array here but `-O2` (GCC auto-vectorization is only done at `-O3` AFAIK and using `-O3` do vectorize the code properly, confirming this). Jagged arrays cause vectorization issues on more complex memory access patterns (e.g. transposition). Also please note that `xx/7.0` is less efficient than `xx*(1/7.0)`. GCC do not perform the conversion unless `-ffast-math` is used (or similar options -- which tends to break the IEEE-754 standard).

Comment: I confirm this is also not the case with GCC 13.2 on ARM with SVE too (using `-O2`). Note that having instructions like `fdiv` or `fadd` does not mean the loop is vectorized : such instruction are actually operating on scalar if scalar values are loaded in SIMD registers. This is what happens (not to mention this is Neon and not SVE instruction if the operand are `sxx` registers, as opposed to `zxx` ones). `-O3` do fix this.

Comment: @JérômeRichard The compiler flags i presented in the question are not the ones im using when i want to vectorize it. I either use `-O3` or specifically use `-ftree-vectorize` and that works. The assembly shows usage of SVE vector instructions `ldw1` etc and usage of vector registers `zXX` aswell as predicate registers.

Comment: `stencil_3d_7point(&A, &B, sz, sy, sz);` Is it intentional that you use `sz` twice and no `sx`?

Comment: @Gerhardh No but they have always been the same value

Answer (score 0):

To swap the entire arrays your way you need:

1. pass the reference to the original pointer as you assign local variables.,

```
void stencil_3d_7point(arr_t *pA, arr_t *pB, const int nx, const int ny, const int nz)
{     arr_t A = *pA;
      arr_t B = *pB;
      /* ... */
      *pA = B;
      *pB = A;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and swapped A and B between iterations using the code in my question `arr_t tmp = A; A = B; B = tmp;`. Still doesn't work. Same results as presented in my question.

Comment: @SimonEngström the way you do it, it will not work

Comment: Would you mind expanding on your answer then?

Comment: @SimonEngström if using this fix does not work for you, please add your updated function at the bottom of your question. Do not delete the old version. Please add the complete modified function together with the modified way to call that function.

Comment: @Gerhardh I've updated the question. Note that I've also flattened the arrays but that was for performance reasons.

Comment: @SimonEngström It is generally a bad idea, doing multiple changes at the same time. It makes it much harder to find root cause for any errors. You should first fix errors with your pointer swapping and only afterwards do some performance improvements.

Comment: @Gerhardh Fair, but I have verified that flattening does not impact the correctness at all. The output is still the exact same as before.